# Problems in R\P (looking for an example)

Tags: computation

I'm studying computability theory, and I'm looking for a problem that clearly can be solved, but not in polynomial time.

I tried thinking of all sort's of examples, but it wasn't clear why they can't be solved in polynomial time..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Problems_in_NP_not_known_to_be_in_P_or_NP-complete

Comment: if P=NP it's not an example...

Comment: so ? you can't say that this is an example! it is well *known* that P!=R and many examples exist.

Comment: so many in fact, that you can't think of one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The travelling sales man problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for something more simple, something that is clearly not in P

Comment: It is very simple. You need to check all the possible paths. Adding a node increases the search space exponentially. There is no shortcuts unlike the shortest path. With the shortest path you can prune the search space.